# Python: Can't pickle type X, attribute lookup failed

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to pickle a `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import cPickle

class Foo:

    Bar = namedtuple('Bar', ['x', 'y'])

    def baz(self):
        s = set()
        s.add(Foo.Bar(x=2, y=3))
        print cPickle.dumps(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo()
    f.baz()
```

This produces the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch.py", line 15, in <module>
    f.baz()
  File "scratch.py", line 11, in baz
    print cPickle.dumps(s)
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Bar'>: attribute lookup __main__.Bar failed
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the problem that `Bar` is a member of `Foo`? (Moving the definition of `Bar` to the top level solves the problem, although I'm still curious why this happens.)

Comment: Using python3 and pickle protocol 4 fixes this

Comment: Is @DaveButler 's answer correct?  Can anyone confirm or deny?

Comment: DaveButler's comment is not correct. But there is a Python-3-specific solution: see [my answer](/a/77930309).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, the fact that it's a class member is a problem:

```
>>> class Foo():
...     Bar = namedtuple('Bar', ['x','y'])
...     def baz(self):
...         b = Foo.Bar(x=2, y=3)
...         print(type(b))
...
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.baz()
<class '__main__.Bar'>
```

The problem is that when `namedtuple()` returns a type object, it isn't aware of the fact that it's being assigned to a class member - and thus, it tells the type object that its type name should be `__main__.Bar`, even though it should really be `__main__.Foo.Bar`.

Comment: `namedtuple` just doesn't play nice with classes. You might be able to write a custom `__getstate__` for the object which would take care of it manually.

Comment: Would an early bind grab that?

Comment: How could I use __getstate__? I don't know how to implement that. At the moment I'm working with a temporary solution that transfers a list of named tuples to a dictionary.

Answer (score 16):

Nesting classes makes pickle fail, since it relies on the path of the object inside your application to reconstruct it later.

The immediate solution is to not nest classes, i.e. move `Bar` definition to outside `Foo`. Code will work all the same.

But a better thing to do is to **not use** `pickle` at all to store data. Use some other serialization format, like `json`, or a database, like `sqlite3`.

You have just hit one of the many inconveniences of pickle, if you change your code, move things around, or sometimes make small structural changes, your data becomes unloadable.

Besides that, pickle has other disadvantages: It is slow, unsecure, python-only...

Answer (score 10):

Using dill in place of pickle here will allow this to work

Comment: `import dill; dill.dumps(x)`

Comment: Also this doesn't work for me. I get: Can't pickle <class 'RoadAttributesPartition'>: it's not found as __main__.RoadAttributesPartition

Comment: Caution: this works because `dill` pickles `namedtuple` classes as code that constructs a new `namedtuple` class. That means that tests like `isinstance(x, Foo.Bar)` will return `False`, and even unpickling the same `dill`-produced buffer twice will get you instances of different classes.

Answer (score 2):

The solution here is to move your named tuple definition to the module level, then pickle works. A detailed answer is provided here:

[How to pickle a namedtuple instance correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377215/how-to-pickle-a-namedtuple-instance-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

If you came here via search engine, the problem could also be that the name of the type and the first parameter are not identical. For example:

```
FooBar = namedtuple('foo_bar', ['x', 'y'])
```

should be

```
FooBar = namedtuple('FooBar', ['x', 'y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.5+, you can fix this by using `typing.NamedTuple` instead of `collections.namedtuple`:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Foo:
    class Bar(NamedTuple):
        x: int
        y: int

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pickle
    s = {Foo.Bar(x=2, y=3)}
    p = pickle.dumps(s, 4)
    assert pickle.loads(p) == s
```