# How to pickle a namedtuple instance correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, namedtuple

I'm learning how to use pickle. I've created a namedtuple object, appended it to a list, and tried to pickle that list. However, I get the following error:

```
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.P'>: it's not found as __main__.P
```

I found that if I ran the code without wrapping it inside a function, it works perfectly. Is there an extra step required to pickle an object when wrapped inside a function?

Here is my code:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pickle

def pickle_test():
    P = namedtuple("P", "one two three four")
    my_list = []
    abe = P("abraham", "lincoln", "vampire", "hunter")
    my_list.append(abe)
    with open('abe.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(abe, f)
    
pickle_test()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, pickle doesn't seem to work well with namedtuples.

Comment: @Antimony: `pickle` handles namedtuple classes just fine; classes defined in a function local namespace not so much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Can't pickle type X, attribute lookup failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677012/python-cant-pickle-type-x-attribute-lookup-failed)

Comment: @AirThomas This question was asked/answered a year ago :)

Comment: That doesn't affect whether it's a duplicate - and now the questions are linked to each other in the sidebar, which is useful. The comment is not meant as a criticism, it's automatically generated when flagging.

Comment: None taken. I just thought it was funny. Question linking is very useful indeed :)

Comment: There is a similar problem. If the type variable and the type string used in the constructor are not the same then pickle will also fail. e.g. `P = namedtuple("Q", "one two three four")`

Comment: For posterity: that error also occurs if the `typename` argument to namedtuple doesn't match the class name returned by namedtuple. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28149627/3396951

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Create the named tuple *outside* of the function:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pickle

P = namedtuple("P", "one two three four")

def pickle_test():
    my_list = []
    abe = P("abraham", "lincoln", "vampire", "hunter")
    my_list.append(abe)
    with open('abe.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(abe, f)

pickle_test()
```

Now `pickle` can find it; it is a module global now. When unpickling, all the `pickle` module has to do is locate `__main__.P` again. In your version, `P` is a *local*, to the `pickle_test()` function, and that is not introspectable or importable.

Note that `pickle` stores just the module and the class name, as taken from the class's `__name__` attribute. Make sure that the first argument of the `namedtuple()` call matches the global variable you are assigning to; `P.__name__` must be `"P"`!

It is important to remember that `namedtuple()` is a class factory; you give it parameters and it returns a class object for you to create instances from. `pickle` only stores the *data* contained in the instances, plus a string reference to the original class to reconstruct the instances again.

Comment: So, what if I am creating the `namedtuple` dynamically because I don't know the fields until runtime? Is there still a way to bypass this issue? I tried creating another method outside of the class but that didn't work.

Comment: @Chuim: Assign it to your module globals (use `globals()` to get a mapping) under the *same name*, and `pickle` can find it still.

Comment: If you are creating multiple namedtuples with dynamic fields, unpickling won't work after you override `P` in `globals`.

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan:  No, each class needs a separate name.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working on Python 3.x

Comment: @facehugger: the technique applies just as much to Python 3 as it did to Python 2. The _test code_ was specific to Python 2, but you can trivially alter that by replacing `"w"` with `"wb"` (open the file in binary mode). I've edited the question and answer to make that change.

Comment: @facehugger: note that the variable name of the named tuple must match the name passed to the namedtuple function. In this case they are both 'P'. If these names differ, attribute lookup will fail.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: could you please edit this question to reflect that the global variable name that the namedtuple is assigned to *must* match the name passed as the first argument in the namedtuple function? In this case they are both `P`. Your edit cue is full, so I can't submit this as an edit.

Comment: @MRule: it is not a hard requirement, it'll just cause a bit of confusion. `Q = namedtuple('P', ...) is just the same as `class P: ...`, then `Q = P` and `del P`. Both would make the class unfindable by pickle, of course.

Comment: I ran some tests and I get the "cannot look up attribute" error every time the names differ. Python3? hmm..

Comment: @MRule: yes, that's what I meant by *would make the class unfindable by pickle*. Had you added `actual_name = other_name` to your module, with `actual_name` matching the firsts argument to `namedtuple()`, it would work again.

Answer (score 14):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28149627/7640677) in another thread.

For pickling to work correctly, the variable assigned to the namedtuple must have the same name as the namedtuple itself

```
group_t =            namedtuple('group_t', 'field1, field2')  # this will work
mismatched_group_t = namedtuple('group_t', 'field1, field2')  # this will throw the error
```

Answer (score 11):

After I added my question as a comment to the main answer I found a way to solve the problem of making a dynamically created `namedtuple` pickle-able. This is required in my case because I'm figuring out its fields only at runtime (after a DB query).

All I do is *monkey patch* the `namedtuple` by effectively moving it to the `__main__` module:

```
def _CreateNamedOnMain(*args):
    import __main__
    namedtupleClass = collections.namedtuple(*args)
    setattr(__main__, namedtupleClass.__name__, namedtupleClass)
    namedtupleClass.__module__ = "__main__"
    return namedtupleClass
```

Mind that the `namedtuple` name (which is provided by `args`) might overwrite another member in `__main__` if you're not careful.

Comment: Simply set it on `globals()` instead: `globals()[namedtupleClass.__name__] = namedtupleClass`. Then there is *no need* to set the `__module__`.

Comment: When I tried `globals()[namedtupleClass.__name__] = namedtupleClass` it did indeed allow me to pickle my object, but when I tried to unpickle it didn't have the `namedtupleClass` it needed. My advice is to **just use a dictionary** until they make pickle smart enough to do this.

Comment: @Teque5 it works as long as then name you pass to `namedtuple()` is unique in the the module

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can use [`cloudpickle`](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle) or [`dill`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) for serialization:

```
from collections import namedtuple

import cloudpickle
import dill



def dill_test(dynamic_names):
    P = namedtuple('P', dynamic_names)
    my_list = []
    abe = P("abraham", "lincoln", "vampire", "hunter")
    my_list.append(abe)
    with open('deleteme.cloudpickle', 'wb') as f:
        cloudpickle.dump(abe, f)
    with open('deleteme.dill', 'wb') as f:
        dill.dump(abe, f)


dill_test("one two three four")
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is the child processes aren't able to import the class of the object -in this case, the class P-, in the case of a multi-model project the Class P should be importable anywhere the child process get used

a quick workaround is to make it importable by affecting it to globals()

```
globals()["P"] = P
```