# How can I "save" an instance and not its reference? (Pickle)

Tags: python, instance, pickle

I'm working with a "bunch-class" just to save attributes.

```
class Args:pass
args = Args()
args.test = "test"
args.bla = [...]
```

Then I pass `args` as `data` to other functions (`data=args`). I think my problem is that only a reference is given to `data`: `data = <__main__.Args object at 0x09E41050>`

Im trying to use Pickle, but this error apears: `pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Args'>: it's not found as __main__.Args`.

I dont know exactly if the problem is caused by the reference, but I think its probably.

Comment: This has nothing to do with references. This has everything to do with Pickle not being able to restore the class for you. `Args.__module__` says it is living in `__main__` but pickle cannot find it back there, and that means you cannot later unpickle the instance.

Comment: I think you'd have better luck implementing a method for `Args` which serialises it's data somehow and pickles that onto disk. Then implement a `load` constructor method which can unpickle and create a new `Args` object with the deserialised data.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here: [Answer from Martijn on other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16377267/3027322)

I was "creating" my bunch class inside a function. That was the problem.
Sorry for the duplicate, should have searched better. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem?  If you use `dill`, instead of `pickle`, `dill` can correctly identify the class definition and correctly associate the class instance with it… hence an instance can be pickled without issue.

```
dude@hilbert>$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 12 2013, 13:26:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill as pickle
>>> class Args: pass
... 
>>> args = Args()
>>> args.test = 'test'
>>> args.bla = ['foo']
>>> 
>>> _args = pickle.dumps(args)
>>> __args = pickle.loads(_args)
>>> __args
<__main__.Args instance at 0x101bf3560>
>>> __args.test
'test'
>>> __args.bla
['foo']
>>>
```

This works in `dill`, because `dill` can pickle the class source instead of needing to pickle the class by name reference (as `pickle` does).

Get `dill` here:  https://github.com/uqfoundation